# How to enable Power BI Web Part in sharepoint online?

Tags: powerbi, sharepoint-online

a) use SharePoint Power BI App to show the report, but there is no Power BI app in SharePoint; 
b) use iframe to show the report, but Power BI don’t have the option of publish to web

Am I missing any Administrator Center Settings?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Embed in SharePoint Online feature in power bi service

Prerequisites:
•   Tenant needs to be enrolled in the Set up standard or first release options in Office 365.
•   The first release for everyone must be selected.
•   Every user must have Power BI pro license to see the report.
•   The user’s account must have access to both the SharePoint site and the Power BI site.
•   The user’s security context is used to load the data from Power BI.  Only data that the user has access to is displayed.
•   The Power BI web part needs modern pages. It can’t be added to classic pages.

For more information go through https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-service-embed-report-spo/